# Ruby macro text substitution

Tags: ruby, text, macros, substitution

I know macros are not possible in Ruby, however, I've run into a situation where I don't know of a workaround.

I have two methods (and I may have more) that are almost identical, and differ only in a couple variable names. Specifically, I swapped the `|n|` and `|m|` in the outer and inner `upto` loops.

```
def self.check_across
  0.upto(4) do |n|
    test = 0
    0.upto(4) { |m| if @@bingo_board[n][m] == "X" then test += 1 end }
    if test == 5 then return true end
  end
  return false
end

def self.check_down
  0.upto(4) do |m|
    test = 0
    0.upto(4) { |n| if @@bingo_board[n][m] == "X" then test += 1 end }
    if test == 5 then return true end
  end
  return false
end
```

In the first method I'm checking a 5x5 bingo board for a complete row of "X" values across, and the second method checks for a complete column of "X" values.

I know that in SAS you can just wrap this method in a `%macro` (if you know what I mean). In Ruby, I know this doesn't work, but what I'm TRYING to do is this:

```
def self.check(x, y)
  0.upto(4) do |x|
    test = 0
    0.upto(4) { |y| if @@bingo_board[n][m] == "X" then test += 1 end }
    if test == 5 then return true end
  end
  return false
end

example.check(n, m)    # same as .check_across
example.check(m, n)    # same as .check_down
```

Of course, this doesn't work since `n` and `m` would be treated as variable names that exist outside of the method.

Comment: You *could* use `define_method`, but... the only thing you need to abstract out is retrieving `@@bingo_board[n][m]`, so you really just need two tiny methods that flip the args, and the larger method that does the loops and the test. Or two simple lambdas you can pass into the loop/test method (probably my preference, but that's just how I roll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a block to accomplish something similar.

For example,

```
def check
  0.upto(4) do |i|
    test = 0
    0.upto(4) do |j|
      # hand control of how to deal with indices over to the calling method
      if yield(i,j) == 'X'
        test += 1
      end
    end
    return true if test == 5
  end
  false
end

def check_across(board)
  check do |i,j|
    # implementing logic for accessing rows
    board[i][j]
  end
end

def check_down(board)
  check do |i,j|
    # implementing logic for accessing columns
    board[j][i]
  end
end
```

And a quick sanity check:

```
a = [
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O)
]

b = [
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O),
%w(X X X X X),
%w(O O O O O),
%w(O O O O O)
]

c = [
%w(O O O X O),
%w(O O O X O),
%w(O O O X O),
%w(O O O X O),
%w(O O O X O)
]

check_across(a) #=> false
check_across(b) #=> true
check_across(c) #=> false

check_down(a) #=> false
check_down(b) #=> false
check_down(c) #=> true
```

Comment: Exactly!  Ruby is just awesomely powerful but - BUT - it forces you to think in different ways sometimes.

Comment: Shouldn't you be fixing something in the dashboard or something?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this untested code:

```
def self.check_across
  @@bingo_board.each do |n|
    return true if n.all?{ |m| m == 'X' }
  end

  false
end

def self.check_down
  @@bingo_board.transpose.each do |m|
    return true if m.all?{ |n| n == 'X' }
  end

  false
end
```

[`transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is a nice method that is useful for this sort of problem. [`all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) makes it easy to see if all elements in an array are the same, and returns true if it does.

---

It looks like those can be DRY'd to:

```
def self.check_across
  @@bingo_board.any?{ |n|
    n.all?{ |m| m == 'X' }
  }
end

def self.check_down
  @@bingo_board.transpose.any?{ |m|
    m.all?{ |n| n == 'X' }
  }
end
```

[`any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is useful to find whether any element matches a condition and returns true. In this case it's whether a row or column is all 'X'.

Comment: Thanks. It's untested because I was out too late and haven't had my morning caffeine.